# Moving some information from one server to another Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3, database

We do have some issues with our Magento 2.3.3 server and we want to move all the customer, products, sales info, and all the stuff that is important from the old server to the new one. Some of the issues are all the 3rd party module that is installed.

The old server is Magento 2.3.3 and the new one is a fresh 2.4 installation. Will this be possible? without bringing all the mess from the old server?

Any help and suggestions are appriciated.

Comment: no one can predict answer as yes or no its all depend on your extension and customization. need to fully test after moving code to 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe would be helpful to start identifying what is giving problems, so that you can avoid bringing it into the new installation. (Look at the logs in /var/logs and var/exceptions)

Also, keep in mind that installing a module may have brought some new tables into your database, which may you not want it into the new installation if the module is disabled or removed.

To approach the data migration you could use the Magento 2 Export/Import function.

I don't know exactly which one is the mess you are talking about, but generally speaking, this is the way I'd approach it.

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for the suggestions. 

The problem we have is that the previous developer left without letting us know what he has done previously. There have been changes in the core files in the vendor folder and not by using app/code folders. That is the mess I'm referring to. 

One example is that he disabled the MSI and when I tried to enable it again things when south and I had to roll back.

This is the reason why we think is best to move to a new and clean server where we know the struckter 100%

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean, and yes it's a mess. Having said that, moving to a new codebase it means you'll need to test the website before putting it live; so you'll see all the problems you may have in the code you are bringing from the old version. For instance, something you may need to do is updating the code which is using deprecated functions, and of course, all the modules.